# Debugging injected DLL with Visual Studio not working

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, debugging, dll

I injected a C++ DLL into a target process like described [here](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/using-createremotethread-for-dll-injection-on-windows/). In Visual Studio I want to debug the injected DLL like a "normal" application. I followed [this](http://www.codereversing.com/blog/archives/219) tutorial which seems reasonable but Visual Studio does not break and only says:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

Why? I'm using the default `Debug` configuration (with debugging symbols I believe). The DLL is injected successfully and executed the `DllMain` but Visual Studio does not "notice" that even though it is attached to the target process. Is there anything "special" I need to consider configuring in Visual Studio?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Dlls are handled lazily, maybe it is just not loaded. Without it symbols also aren't loaded. Did You try to make a call to the function exported by that dll and have breakpoint inside of it?

Comment: Have you tried to change the path to the PDB file by passing the /PDBALTPATH option and a relative path to the linker? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363404/injected-dll-cant-use-symbols-pdb-unless-its-in-the-same-directory-as-build

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza, What about this issue now? As the error message is that it couldn't load the symbols, could you visit the Modules window and find more information there? Maybe you could put all symbols to your dll path and load it manually from the Debug Modules window. Anyway, if you get any latest information,feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know even if the Dll was built with Debug configuration it won't contain all symbols necessary for debugging. You will still need its symbol file which is generated when building.
I assume you didn't build the DLL yourself because otherwise Visual Studio should be able to find the symbol file on your disk by itself. The symbol file has .pdb as extension and usually resides inside the build folder. You need to locate it and tell Visual Studio where to search for it during your debug session. When you have found the symbol file select "Debugging" from Visual Studio's menu bar and follow this path: "Options" => "Debugging" => "Symbols". Hit the button with the green plus sign to add the location where the symbol file resides. Take note that you only need to add the file's location, specifying its name is not required.

Comment: Apparently you did build the dll yourself so my answer probably is not what you are looking for...

Comment: Yeah, I built it myself so I have all configuration options available.